# How to "connect" different User Interfaces to each other in jDev

Tags: java, user-interface, uml

I have a question. I am creating a User Interface for an UML-model.

When I execute my User Interface (the application), I first want a "main menu"-frame to pop up, giving me 3 different choices (Buttons to push).

---

For example, I want the "main menu"- frame to show me this:

```
                     Customer(button1)

                     Product(button2)

                     Order(button3)
```

---

When I for example click on the "Customer"-button I want it to access the "Customer"- frame which is a separate frame where there will be other buttons, textfields etcetera.

Bear in mind that I am a noob in Java, it's the first semester in school.

How do I make this possible?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, could you clarify and simplify your question. Is it the actual Java code you need help with? or the design in UML?

Comment: It's the Java Code. For example in my imagination the customer-button is connected to a "method" which directs me to a certain action (in this case to another frame). I've only made one User Interface for the code before. Here I want 4 different frames. One, which is a "main-frame" which holds keys to enter the other frames. Hopes this helps.